# bootstrap navbar collapse not working with good jQuery order?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

jQuery order is correct as I,ve called `bootstrap.js` after the jQuery but `navbar` is not working. Could you please help why is that not working?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">             
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="myNavbar">
              <span class="icon-bar top-bar"> </span>
              <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"> </span>  
              <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"> </span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">home</a>
        </div>
        <div class="bar collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">            
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li> <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"> Home </a> </li>
                <li> <a class="navbar-brand" href="About.php"> About   </a> </li>
                <li> <a class="navbar-brand" href="contact.php"> Contact </a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `#` in `data-target` attribute.

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="myNavbar">
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^
It should be #myNavbar
```

Following code should work.

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">

      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">

        <span class="icon-bar top-bar"> </span>
        <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"> </span>  
        <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"> </span> 

      </button>

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> home </a>

    </div>

    <div class="bar collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar" >

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li> <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"> Home </a> </li>
        <li> <a class="navbar-brand" href="About.php"> About   </a> </li>
        <li> <a class="navbar-brand" href="contact.php"> Contact </a> </li>
      </ul>   

    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I added the #, and Navbar drops down,  but it is not collapsing again I meant it's not closing

Comment: @Digitalgo but its working properly in above demo, may be you have some other conflicting issues?

Comment: Can you tell me any other possibilities, because I am newbie, I have placed the jquery and bootstrap js at the head section??

Comment: @Digitalgo you can create a fiddle of all your current code and give me link, I'll try to look what is the issue

Comment: i changed the order of bootstrap and jquery i.e. i called the bootstrap first and jquery second. now the navbar working nice.